# Get data to FragmentDialog from Activity

Tags: android-fragments

How to set Title in FragmentDialog with text from Activity?

Answer (score 0):

You can try use arguments to do so:

On your activity:

```
Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
Fragment fragment = new YourDialogFragment();
arguments.putSerializable(KEYNAME, YOUR_SERIALIZABLE_ITEM);
fragment.setArguments(arguments);               
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.your, fragment).commit();
```

On your fragment:

```
if (getArguments().containsKey(KEYNAME))
(ObjectType) getArguments().getSerializable(KEYNAME);
```